# R - Search for a text string in a data frame column and replace contents/make a new column

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a pretty simple thing.  I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4","ID5", "ID6", "ID7", "ID8"),
             variable=c("XXX.C1", "XXY.I2", "XXZ.J3", "XYZ.C4", "YXX.C1", "XZX.I2", "XYX.J3", "XXA.C4"))
```

Giving the data frame:

```
ID variable
1 ID1   XXX.C1
2 ID2   XXY.I2
3 ID3   XXZ.J3
4 ID4   XYZ.C4
5 ID5   YXX.C1
6 ID6   XZX.I2
7 ID7   XYX.J3
8 ID8   XXA.C4
```

I'd like to do a couple of different things.

1. How can I select all the entries in the 'variable' column  ending with 'C1 and replace those entries with simply 'C1', that is, replace all the text in front of 'C1'.  And perform the same for those entries ending 'I2', 'J3', and 'C4'.
2. How can I select all the entries in the 'variable' column ending with 'C1' and make a new column named 'variable2' with just this text ('C1').  And do the same for those entries ending in 'I2', 'J3', and 'C4'.

I apologize in advance if this has been covered in a previous question.  Much thanks!

PS

Comment: Example code doesn't match contents of example data frame.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `tidyverse`

1- Use `dplyr::mutate` with `gsub`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(variable=gsub(x=variable, ".*(C.)", "\\1"))

   ID variable
1 ID1       C1
2 ID2       C2
3 ID3       C3
4 ID4       C4
5 ID5       C1
6 ID6       C2
7 ID7       C3
8 ID8       C4
```

2- use `tidyr::spread` to the result of (1)

```
df %>% 
  mutate(variable=gsub(x=variable, ".*(C.)", "\\1")) %>%
  spread(key = variable, value = variable)

   ID   C1   C2   C3   C4
1 ID1   C1 <NA> <NA> <NA>
2 ID2 <NA>   C2 <NA> <NA>
3 ID3 <NA> <NA>   C3 <NA>
4 ID4 <NA> <NA> <NA>   C4
5 ID5   C1 <NA> <NA> <NA>
6 ID6 <NA>   C2 <NA> <NA>
7 ID7 <NA> <NA>   C3 <NA>
8 ID8 <NA> <NA> <NA>   C4
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  Very useful.